# sql row value as column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
| calendar_week | task       | person |
| 1             | cooking    | Bernd  |
| 1             | cleaning   | Julia  |
| 2             | carwashing | Bernd  |
| 2             | cleaning   | James  |
```

is it somehow possible to get the output like this:

```
| calendar_week | cooking | cleaning | carwashing |
| 1             | Bernd   | Julia    |            |
| 2             |         | James    | Bernd      |
```

So the different tasks should become columns and the tasks are 'random'.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    calendar_week,
    max(case when task = 'cooking' then person end) cooking,
    max(case when task = 'cleaning' then person end) cleaning,
    max(case when task = 'carwashing' then person end) carwashing
from mytable
group by calendar_week
```

This works over a *fixed list of tasks*, since a SQL query must returned a fixed, pre-defined list of columns. If you are dealing with a unpredictable number of tasks, then you would need to either use dynamic SQL, or, as commented by Strawberry, to handle the pivoting in your application instead of database.

Comment: and the tasks are 'random'.

Comment: @Strawberry: right. I updated my answer with more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

one of the solution to this is using join.

```
select t1.tableA, coalesce(t2.person, '') as cooking
    , coalesce(t3.person, '') as cleaning
    , coalesce(t4.person, '') as carwashing
from (select distinct calendarweek from tableA) t1
left join tableA t2 on t2.calendarweek = t1.calendarweek and t2.task = 'cooking'
left join tableA t3 on t3.calendarweek = t1.calendarweek and t3.task = 'cleaning'
left join tableA t4 on t4.calendarweek = t1.calendarweek and t4.task = 'carwashing'
```

Comment: and the tasks are 'random'.